# How to proceed when correlation plot doesn't show as much multicorrelation as is seen by statsmodels variance_inflation_factor in a regression task?

Tags: regression, python, multicollinearity, variance-inflation-factor, pandas

I am working with the kaggle Blueberry Yield prediction dataset. There are 17 columns including the target variable. Below is the correlation heat map:

[image: correlation-heat-map]

It can be seen that multiple features are correlated among themselves in a linear manner. Therefore, to find the non-linear relationships, I proceeded with `statsmodels's` `variance_inflation_factor` and this is the result:

[image: VIF-table]

*What I made out of this VIF table is that:*

```
1. Almost every feature is correlated with one or more other features. Therefore, there exists excessive multicorrelation.

2. If I take the VIF threshold to be 5 and remove the features exceeding this, no feature excluding `honeybee` will be left.

3. Columns 5 to 16 (16th is the target variable) shows abnormally high VIF score!
```

So, in order to proceed with regression model fitting, if I remove every highly multi-correlated feature, I will be left only with `honeybee` and `yield`.

**How do I treat the result of the above VIF score, so that I won't go wrong with the model fitting, which features should I take?**

Comment: Welcome to CV.  Your example shows vividly why VIF is not a useful tool for model identification.  So, reframe how you conceptualize the problem: *you need to find a subset of variables that predict the target accurately.* Search our site for related keywords.  Choose among model, variable, identification, lasso, svm, glmnet, regularization, training, and testing.

Comment: Warning: statsmodels's variance_inflation_factor assumes that there is a constant in the data or that the data has been demeaned. It was designed to be used with a model design matrix.